# Add another annotation when an annotation is present with Java 8

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I am currently creating my own CRUD-managing class. For this purpose I work with an annotation that looks like this:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface DTO {
    String table() default "";
}
```

Every object annotated with this annotation also needs to have the "NoArgsConstructor"-Annotation from lombok, which can only be applied to class or enum types. Therefore I cannot just add it on top of the annotations of the definition of DTO. How can I achieve, that every class that has the DTO-Annotation also receives the NoArgsConstructor without it being required to add it every time manually?

This works fine:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@DTO(table = "cast2")
public class CastDTO {
    @Column
    private Integer mid;
    @Column
    private Integer pid;
    @Column
    private String role;
}
```

but I'd rather not have to add `NoArgsConstructor` every time I create another Class.

Comment: As long as you don't have any required fields in you class, you shouldn't need `@NoArgsConstructor`. By default java has a no args constructor for every class, unless otherwise specified. As soon as you have required fields in your class, then you need to specify `@NoArgsConstructor` as well as `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. This was [just recently asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72226209/lombok-data-annotation-does-not-add-required-args-constructor-when-no-args-const)

Comment: NoArgsConstructor being a compile-time annotation (because it needs to generate the constructor over compilation), you'll need to handle such task with an [annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder). You can follow the example in the link, the idea would be to get all elements annotated by your DTO annotation, and add to them the NoArgsConstructor annotation in the pre-compilation round.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer unfortunately my code doesn't compile without the NoArgsConstructor being specified. I also think this this is curious, since I thought the Data-Annotation would take care of this as well as Java by default...